# Obtener variable GET en javascript para pasarla por AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, get

Tengo un archivo `JavasCript`

```
/*===========================================
CARGAR TABLA DE VENTAS DINAMICAMENTE
===========================================*/

toPost = { fechaInicial: '2020-01-01', fechaFinal: '2020-02-01' };

$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/datatable-ventas.ajax.php",
    data: toPost,
    method: "GET",
    success: function(respuesta) {
        console.log(respuesta)
    }
})



$("#tablaVentas").dataTable({

    "ajax": "ajax/datatable-ventas.ajax.php",
    "deferRender": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "retrieve": true,
    "processing": true,
    "language": {

        "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
        "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
        "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
        "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
        "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_",
        "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0",
        "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
        "sInfoPostFix": "",
        "sSearch": "Buscar:",
        "sUrl": "",
        "sInfoThousands": ",",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst": "Primero",
            "sLast": "Último",
            "sNext": "Siguiente",
            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
        },
        "oAria": {
            "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
            "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
        }
    }

});
```

y en el archivo `ajax/datatable-ventas.ajax.php`

```
<?php


require_once "../controladores/ventas.controlador.php";
require_once "../modelos/ventas.modelo.php";

require_once "../controladores/clientes.controlador.php";
require_once "../modelos/clientes.modelo.php";
require_once "../controladores/usuarios.controlador.php";
require_once "../modelos/usuarios.modelo.php";


class TablaVentas{

/*=============================================
 MOSTRAR LA TABLA DE VENTAS
=============================================*/ 

public function mostrarTablaVentas(){


if(isset($_GET["fechaInicial"])){

    $fechaInicial = $_GET["fechaInicial"];
    $fechaFinal = $_GET["fechaFinal"];
}else{
    $fechaInicial = null;
    $fechaFinal = null;
}

  $respuesta = ControladorVentas::ctrRangoFechasVentas($fechaInicial, $fechaFinal);




   $datosJson = '{"data":[';

    for($i=0;$i < count($respuesta);$i++){



        $item = "id";
        $valor = $respuesta[$i]["id_cliente"];
        $cliente = ControladorClientes::ctrMostrarClientes($item,$valor);

        $valor2 = $respuesta[$i]["id_vendedor"];
        $vendedor = ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarUsuarios($item,$valor2);

        $botones = "<button class='btn btn-warning btnEditarVenta' idVenta='".$respuesta[$i]['id']."'><i class='fa fa-pencil-alt'></i></button><button class='btn btn-danger btnEliminarVenta' idVenta='".$respuesta[$i]['id']."'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button>";





        $datosJson .= '[
                    "'.($respuesta[$i]["codigo"]).'",
                    "'.$cliente["nombre"].'",
                    "'.$vendedor["nombre"].'",
                    "'.$respuesta[$i]["metodo_pago"].'",
                    "'.$respuesta[$i]["precio_servicios"].'",
                    "'.$respuesta[$i]["precio_productos"].'",
                    "'.$respuesta[$i]["fecha"].'",
                    "'.$botones.'"
        ],';
    }

    $datosJson = substr($datosJson, 0, -1);
    $datosJson .= ']}';
    echo $datosJson;

    return;


}

}



/*=============================================
 ACTIVAR LA TABLA DE VENTAS
  =============================================*/ 

  $activarVentas = new TablaVentas();
  $activarVentas -> mostrarTablaVentas();
```

> El codigo indicado anteriormente, el cual funciona correctamente si yo no utilizo el filtro de fechas, es decir que las rutas y los directorios estan bien.
>   Ademas, si pruebo darle valores a las variables $fechaFinal y $fechaInicial al estilo '20-12-2020', la respuesta es correcta (osea que el problema está de ahi para atras)

Si yo utilizo el codigo mostrado mas arriba, me deja las variables $fechaInicial y $fechaFinal en `null`. No entiendo porque la condicion `if(isset($_GET["fechaFinal"])` devuelve `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te comenta @A.Cedano es correcto, sin embargo tu pregunta inicial refiere a obtener los datos de la url, para ello necesitas el objeto `location`, y para obtener los parámetros de get debes apuntar a `search`, te devolverá un string y puedes añadirlo a tus url para ajax

```
console.log(location.search)
```

Comment: Es cierto, de la forma que me decis, con un substring pude obtener los GET, el tema es que si hago lo que me indica @a.cedano, de todas maneras la funcion en el datatable-ventas.ajax.php sigue dando false la condicion de ``isset($_GET["fechaInicial"]``

Comment: Y ¿probaste lo que te indiqué en mi respuesta?

Comment: Lo habia probado en la primer llamada ajax, sin embargo como me dice @A.Cedano, la llamada ajax la estaba manejando ``DataTables``, cuando lo probé ahi funcionó

Answer (score 1):

Ajax de jQuery tiene un parámetro `data` para pasar los valores.

Aunque puedes pasarla hardcodeada en forma de url, lo más limpio es crea un objeto y pasar ese objeto en el parámetro `data`.

Algo así:

```
var toPost={fechaInicial: fechaInicial, fechaFinal: fechaFinal};

$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/datatable-ventas.ajax.php",
    data: toPost,
    method: "GET",
    success: function(respuesta) {
        console.log(respuesta)
    }
})
```

El objeto `toPost` se crea al estilo JSON, con pares clave : valor, donde el dato de la izquierda es el nombre de la clave y el de la derecha es el valor. Cada par de valores se separa por comas.

He aprovechado también para indicar el método.

Comment: No funciona, entiendo que te falto ponerle comillas al dato {fechaInicial: "fechaInicial", fechaFinal: "fechaFinal"};, de lo contrario da error. Una vez puesto, sucede lo mismo. Sale por el ``else``de la condicion de la funcion ``mostrarTablaVentas``, como que no llega una variable GET de nombre "fechaInicial"

Comment: @AgustinG. claro, yo asumí que los datos de la derecha ya existían en variables llamadas `fechaInicial` y `fechaFinal` Si no es así, declara variables que recojan los datos o bien prueba primero a ponerlos a mano, algo así: `var toPost={fechaInicial: '2020-01-01', fechaFinal: '2020-02-01'};` y luego lo cambias por variable:

Comment: @AgustinG. otra cosa que tienes que verificar es que estás mandando la petición a la URL correcta. Si tienes: `ajax/datatable-ventas.ajax.php` significa que, el archivo estará en una carpeta `ajax` que contiene la carpeta donde está el archivo de tu petición Ajax. ¿Es así?

Comment: Asi es, la conexion entre archivos ya existe, ya que por ajax estoy recuperando datos y se hace correctamente. Ahora yo quiero filtrar esos datos por rango de fecha. Lo que me indicas lo entendi, pero sigue sin funcionar. Ahora edito la respuesta probando lo que intenté. capaz me esta faltando algo mas

Comment: ahi edite la pregunta agregando al final lo que probe, sin exito. Estará en ``
if(isset($_GET["fechaInicial"])){`` el problema??

Comment: @AgustinG. muestra cómo recibes el GET en PHP y llamas a la función. Y di cómo tienes organizados los archivos. El código debería funcionar si todo está bien dirigido. Y muestra el código real. Por ejemplo aquí te falta un punto y coma: `return`  Y... a `toPost` ponle `var` delante, por si acaso: `var toPost = {  ` ... etc ....

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105592/discussion-between-a-cedano-and-agustin-g).